# Sort List<String> by priorised starting letters

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

As an example, i have a list looking like this:

`["a: foo", "b: bar", "c: foo", "d: bar"]`

I want to sort it so a given priority, for example b > c > every other char.
So the result should be:

`["b: bar", "c: foo", "a: foo", "d: bar"]`

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, just like any sorting of a list it can be simply done by creating your own custom Comparator. Have a look at `java.util.Comparator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the "B then C then other letters" sorting rule to apply to the entire string, not just the first letter, use a custom [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html).

*Example*

```java
String addOnRule = "&b,B<c,C<a,A"; // Sort B then C before A
RuleBasedCollator standardCollator = (RuleBasedCollator) Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
RuleBasedCollator customCollator = new RuleBasedCollator(standardCollator.getRules() + addOnRule);

String[] strings = { "a: foo", "b: bar", "c: foo", "d: bar", "aad", "aac", "aab", "aaa" };
Arrays.sort(strings, customCollator);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
```

*Output*

```
[b: bar, c: foo, a: foo, aab, aac, aaa, aad, d: bar]
```

Answer (score 2):

Define a `Set` containing the priority letters:

```
Set<Character> priority = Set.of ('b', 'c');
```

Then define a comparator which determines if the word starts with a priority letter:

```
Comparator<String> pc = Comparator.comparing(s -> s.isEmpty() || !priority.contains(s.charAt(0)));
```

Then chain this comparator so it breaks ties with natural ordering:

```
Comparator<String> chained = pc.thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Then use this to sort your list:

```
list.sort(chained);
```